# Copy over the previous rows data until there is a mismatch found in current and previous data

Tags: oracle11g

Our DB is Oracle 11g. I have a table with the structure is as shown below:

### Person_Id |  Eff_Dt    |   Wid | Prv_Wid

P1       |    1/1/2001  | 2001 |
P1       |    1/10/2001 | 2001 |
P1       |   10/10/2001 | 2002 |
P1       |   1/1/2002   | 2003 |
P1       |  5/4/2002    | 2003 |
P1       |   8/6/2002   | 2002 |
P1       |   1/1/2005   | 2001 |
P1       |   1/10/2006  | 2001 |

I have a requirement that the Prv_Wid should be derived from the previous row's WID. But if the current and previous WIDs are same, then I have to go to the old previous row where the WID is different and put it in my current row's Prv_Wid.
It should be as shown below:

### Person_Id | Eff_Dt | Wid| Prv_Wid

P1        | 1/1/2001    |    2001   |    0
P1        | 1/10/2001   |    2001   |    0
P1        | 10/10/2001  |    2002   |  2001
P1        |  1/1/2002   |    2003   |  2002
P1        |  5/4/2002   |    2003   |  2002
P1        |  8/6/2002   |    2002   |  2003
P1        |  1/1/2005   |    2001   |  2002
P1        | 1/10/2006   |    2001   |  2002

I have tried several ways like lead, lag, first_value, last_value and procedure
to achieve. But, I am not successful. Could you please provide any solution.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This forum is only for programming. for database questions use http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AshkanSirous - this **is** a programming question (specifically in SQL), not a database administration question. Please note that the dba. ... site is for database **administration**, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... you can change it to an `insert` or `merge` statement as needed. The trick is to prepare your data first, by adding several nulls as demonstrated in the `prep` CTE (you may want to select from `prep` to see what it does - not needed for the final solution, but needed so that you understand how this works).

`EFF_DT` in the output uses my date format model settings.

```
with
     tbl ( Person_Id, Eff_Dt, Wid, Prv_Wid ) as (
       select 'P1', to_date(  '1/1/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2001, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date( '1/10/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2001, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date('10/10/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2002, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date(  '1/1/2002', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2003, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date(  '5/4/2002', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2003, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date(  '8/6/2002', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2002, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date(  '1/1/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2001, null from dual union all
       select 'P1', to_date( '1/10/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2001, null from dual
     ),
     prep ( person_id, eff_dt, wid, prv_wid ) as (
       select person_id, eff_dt, wid,
              case when wid != lag(wid) over (partition by person_id order by eff_dt) 
                   then lag(wid) over (partition by person_id order by eff_dt) end
       from   tbl
     )
select person_id, eff_dt, wid, 
       nvl(last_value(prv_wid ignore nulls) 
           over (partition by person_id order by eff_dt), 0) as prv_wid
from prep
;

PE EFF_DT                     WID    PRV_WID
-- ------------------- ---------- ----------
P1 2001-01-01 00:00:00       2001          0
P1 2001-10-01 00:00:00       2001          0
P1 2001-10-10 00:00:00       2002       2001
P1 2002-01-01 00:00:00       2003       2002
P1 2002-04-05 00:00:00       2003       2002
P1 2002-06-08 00:00:00       2002       2003
P1 2005-01-01 00:00:00       2001       2002
P1 2006-10-01 00:00:00       2001       2002

 8 rows selected
```